# Twilio voicemail hangs up immediately

Tags: c#, .net, twilio, twilio-api

I have some code that is pretty much straight from the examples (https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/browser-calls-csharp-mvc)

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Connect(string phoneNumber, string called)
{
    var response = new VoiceResponse();

    var dial = new Dial(callerId: _credentials.PhoneNumber, timeout: 10);
    if (phoneNumber != null)
    {
        dial.Number(phoneNumber);
    }
    else
    {
        int agentId = 1;
        dial.Client("support_agent");
    }
    response.Dial(dial);

    return TwiML(response);
}
```

However, when the code is called the phone hangs up immediately without forwarding to the support agent.

Also, if I make an outgoing call the action is called but the phone call is never received.

It sounds like a configuration issue, but I have no idea where to look.

A hint, when I try and call the number in Twilio console I get **Cannot establish connection. Client is disconnected.**

Comment: Which example is this from? That would help me troubleshoot this for you and hopefully fix it for the future :)

Comment: I have included a link to the examples.

Comment: Can you provide more context about what you expect to happen? Should it go to voicemail or to an agent? And what's on the other end of 'support agent'? It makes sense that it would hang up if you don't have a client established - there's no more TwiML, so the call ends.

Comment: I expect it to go to an agent, and if they don't answer within 10 seconds go to a voicemail. "support_agent" is pretty much the same as the example, it is a Javascript client.

Comment: Do you have the client connected? The "Client is disconnected" message suggests your client is not available, and since there is no further TwiML that's the end of the call.

Comment: How can I check the client is connected? It all appears ok? I am using the Js library and generating the token etc.